# Etymology: Quechuan (home for homeless languages?)

Tags: discussion, etymology

I have a question relating to the etymology of a word in Quechuan ("guano"). I know nothing of Quechuan: the other three words I'm interested in are PIE (which I can navigate around)(*). I would like to ask for either the etymology of that word, or for the linguistic history of Quechuan (if known), or anything along those lines which could help.

I realise that it's probably better for Russian, German, English, etc, etymologies to live in their respective SE's. I don't know if a question like this would be welcome in Linguistics SE merely because of its otherwise homelessness.

Etymology seems somewhat controversial here, so I thought I would ask on meta.

(*) three words which begin with C, A, and T in English, :-) .

Answer (score 2):

Etymology questions are in principle on-topic.

Your question might be well received if you can show you've done some research of some kind. I'm not sure if there exists even a single etymological reference for Quechua. So you might need to do some original research.